# How do I create video clips that demo the sequence I'm using?

Tags: discussion

Some responses to my questions show a short video clip that demos the actions they recommend.  How are those video clips created?

Comment: Hi ttom, your question was migrated here to meta because it was *about* the site. In the future, any questions that you have *about* BSE, and it's questions or answers should be asked here. Please read through the question this question has been linked to, it should answer your question (I use LiceCap by the way).

Comment: screen capture tools like [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/) seem to be the most popular.

Comment: depends on your operating system. What r u using? windows? macOS?